# Sharding collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Imagine I have a sharded collection with a shard key on the field "abc".
In which shard Mongo will put a document without this field?

It is just a curiosity, a sort of if-case scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to insert a document without this field.

Answer (score 0):

Just made a try. 
On more detail on Sergio's answer:
when you insert a doc w/o the key shard in a sharded collection

db.collection.insert(doc)

you'll receive

WriteResult({
        "nInserted" : 0,
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 61,
                "errmsg" : "document { _id: ObjectId('5a7e1bc22d39792fb5e2a21b'), doc } **does not contain shard key for pattern { : 1.0 }**"
        }
})